# INSERT statement status in VBA using ADODB

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Say i have a table in Excel:
**TableA:**
ID,
Name,
Work,
DOB
I have an insert query like:

```
Insert into TableA(ID,Name,Work,DOB) values (....);
```

I have created the code to upload this data into SQL Server database using ADODB
The upload works fine but i am trying to have it fill the status of the upload such (Pending, Successful) next to each row. Is there any way to do it?
The ending part of my code is:

```
For lp = 0 To qryindex - 1 'this loop is used to get query from the array which is stored in previous loop  
con.Open 'open the connection  
con.Execute qryary(lp), dbfailonerror ' execute the query one by one according to index value  
oldValue = Application.ActiveCell.Value  
con.Close

Next lp  
MsgBox "Data Updated Successfully"  
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

I need it to update the coulmn(F) as each query in the array is successfully posted

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Are you wanting to update the column in Excel? Remember that your execute will complete before it returns to your VBA code. So not sure that changing to Pending and Successful is really worth the effort. By the time your code runs it will already be done. Honestly I would consider use BULK INSERT instead of doing this row by agonizing row.

Comment: As Sean mentioned, you don't need to do this line by line. I would create a  temporary table in the SQL database and then use a SQL statement to add all of the temporary table records to the table you want. It will not take more than seconds even if you have thousands of records. Plus, if an error occurs in the middle of execution it will not leave the records there meaning you can use rollback so either you can successfully insert all of the records or none (then you can try again after fixing the problem)